# OpenGL GLSL shaders statistic

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I am searching program or gl function to get number of local parameter, instructions and another parameters for my GLSL shader. I tried to use GPU ShaderAnalyzer, but it does not help me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what kind of statistics you're looking for, or what exactly you're referring to by "local parameters", but you can get some information back from compiled shaders through the OpenGL API [`glGetProgram`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glGetProgram.xml) and the functions in the "Associated Gets" section of that article.